# Flood fill difficulty in C graphics

Tags: c, flood-fill, bgi, turbo-c

*(Note: My college is making me study graphics in ancient Turbo C)*

Anyway I am using the inbuilt algorithm for floodfill to color a well and a bucket.

The problem I am facing is that the compiler fills the region upto a boundary color. However I would like to fill a basic figure (eliipse here) irrespective of the boundary.
How will one do that?

I did some **testing** as shown below,

[image]

Pic1, *Filled bucket before  drawing well, So well draws over the blue*
Pic2, *Drew well before flood filling bucket, So fills only one part*

My Code:

```
#include<graphics.h>
#include<stdio.h>
void well()
{
    ellipse(50,150,0,360,50,20); //Hole of the well
    arc(50,120,180,300,100);
    line(0,150,0,206);
    line(100,150,100,206);

    line(0,150,0,100);
    line(0,100,50,100);
    circle(50,100,10);

    setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL,RED);
    floodfill(20,170,WHITE);
}
void bucket(int j)
{
    ellipse(50,j,0,360,20,10);    //The Ellipse to be filled as blue
    line(40,j+40,60,j+40);
    line(40,j+40,30,j);
    line(60,j+40,70,j);
    setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL,BLUE);
    floodfill(50,j,WHITE);
}
void main()
{
    int gdriver = DETECT, gmode,i;
    initgraph(&gdriver, &gmode, "C:\\TC\\BGI");

    cleardevice();

    well();
    bucket(130);

    getch();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you draw a solid ellipse (`fillellipse`) on the same position and with the same size? Does it really need to contain a bucket-fill algorithm?

Comment: Try using "fillellipse" instead of "ellipse"

Comment: Turbo C, BGI, oh my!

Comment: They're just making their life harder than it should be.. with these legendary compilers from the very first known millenia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [fillellipse()](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/doc/fillellipse.html) instead of ellipse().